# Dev machine as part of Minikube's network?

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, minikube

Is it possible to have my development machine to be part of Minikube's network?

Ideally, it should work both ways:

- While developing an application in my IDE, I can access k8s resources inside Minikube using the same addressing that pods would use.
- Pods running in Minikube can access my application running in the IDE, for example via HTTP requests.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738500/google-container-engine-and-vpn) sounds like the first part is feasible on GCE using network routes, so I wonder if it's doable locally using Minikube.

Comment: Did you really mean "part of the network" of "being able to access the network"?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your excellent answer (haven't had time to try it out yet though)! From what I understand, this approach would help to "access the network", e.g. talk to services inside Minikube without making them publicly available. Ideally, I would like to be "part of the network" as well, so that pods running in Minikube could for example make HTTP requests to the application I'm running in IntelliJ.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that aspect, sorry if I renamed your title to something not 100% accurate! Would you mind adding that detail to the question and update (revert) the title to make the intention clearer?

Answer (score 12):

There is an issue open upstream ([kubernetes/minikube#38](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/38)) in order to discuss that particular use case.

`kube-proxy` already adds the IPtables rules needed for IP forwarding inside the `minikube` VM (this is not specific to minikube), so all you have to do is add a static route to the container network via the IP of minikube's eth1 interface on your local machine:

```
ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 192.168.42.58 (Linux)
route -n add 10.0.0.0/24 192.168.42.58     (macOS)
```

Where `10.0.0.0/24` is the container network CIDR and `192.168.42.58` is the IP of your minikube VM (obtained with the `minikube ip` command).

You can then reach Kubernetes services from your local environment using their cluster IP. Example:

```
❯ kubectl get svc -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   10.0.0.56    <nodes>       80:30000/TCP   35s
```

[image: kubedash]

This also allows you to resolve names in the `cluster.local` domain via the cluster DNS (`kube-dns` addon):

```
❯ nslookup kubernetes-dashboard.kube-system.svc.cluster.local 10.0.0.10
Server:     10.0.0.10
Address:    10.0.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes-dashboard.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.0.56
```

If you also happen to have a local `dnsmasq` running on you local machine you can easily take advantage of this and forward all DNS requests for the `cluster.local` domain to `kube-dns`:

```
server=/cluster.local/10.0.0.10
```

Comment: If you are using `dnsmask` on macOS, don't forget to configure the resolver to send `cluster.local` requests to dnsmask with `echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" | sudo tee /etc/resolver/cluster.local`