# Minikube expose MySQL running on localhost as service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have minikube version v0.17.1 running on my machine. I want to simulate the environment I will have in AWS, where my MySQL instance will be outside of my Kubernetes cluster.

Basically, how can I expose my local MySQL instance running on my machine to the Kubernetes cluster running via minikube?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046113/minikube-not-able-to-connect-a-locally-deployed-nginx-service) will help you?

Comment: Not really, or at least I'm not sure. Most posts, including this one, seem to talk about how you can access a service running in Kubernetes from your localhost, while I want the exact opposite: expose a port on my localhost and have it available in my Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 15):

Kubernetes allows you to create a service without selector, and cluster will not create related endpoint for this service, this feature is usually used to proxy a legacy component or an outside component.

1. Create a service without selector

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
       name: my-service
   spec:
       ports:
           - protocol: TCP
             port: 1443
             targetPort: <YOUR_MYSQL_PORT>
   ```
2. Create a relative Endpoint object

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Endpoints
   metadata:
       name: my-service
   subsets:
       - addresses:
           - ip: <YOUR_MYSQL_ADDR>
         ports:
           - port: <YOUR_MYSQL_PORT>
   ```
3. Get service IP

   ```
   $ kubectl get svc my-service
   NAME         CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
   my-service   <SERVICE_IP>   <none>        1443/TCP    18m
   ```
4. Access your MYSQL from service `<SERVICE_IP>:1443` or `my-service:1443`

Comment: For inter-pod reference, the service name "my-service" could be used in place of configuration of other pods. Just need to make sure you find the IP "<YOUR_MASQL_ADDR>" in the same network section.

Comment: It worked, You may use my-service:1443 instead of <SERVICE_IP>:1443

Comment: but what do you put for YOUR_MYSQL_ADDR when it is running on localhost?

Comment: @Calicoder That should be the ip address of the machine running the mysql database.  For mysql i had to adjust the database's bind-address

Comment: It is not working even when we add mysql local host address. I have been trying for 4 days.

Comment: Chaning the bind address was key for me

Answer (score 5):

As of minikube 1.10, there is a [special hostname](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/#hostminikubeinternal) `host.minikube.internal` that resolves to the host running the minikube VM or container.  You can then configure this hostname in your pod's environment variables or the ConfigMap that defines the relevant settings.

Comment: Unfortunate for OP, but this should be the accepted answer for those with minikube 1.10+

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 - use a headless service without selectors**

Because this service has no selector, the corresponding `Endpoints` object will not be created. You can manually map the service to your own specific endpoints (See [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)).

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.0.2.2
  ports:
  - port: 8080
```

---

**Option 2 - use [`ExternalName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) service**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: minikube.host
```

The only caveat is that it needs to be able to resolve `minikube.host`. Simply add this line to the `etc/hosts` file should do it.

```
10.0.2.2        minikube.host
```

`ExternalName` doesn't support port mapping at the moment.

---

Another note: The IP `10.0.2.2` is known to work with Virtual Box only (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1261975/1035008)).
For `xhyve`, try replacing that with `192.168.99.1` (see GitHub [issue](https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/issues/196#issuecomment-328363611) and [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2735)). A demo [GitHub](https://github.com/yzhong52/microservices-demo#hybrid).

Answer (score 0):

- Follow instructions in https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/
- You need then obtain your pc IP `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}` --> This one is for mac, you can find similar command to linx, windows
- `minikube ssh` and copy printed IP and pasted in `\etc\hosts` as it says and it should work
- Note use `host.minikube.internal` as mysql host and exposed MySQL port.

Answer (score -1):

Just a reminder, if on Windows, open your firewall.