# On a Mac, what IP will represent my laptop from within a minikube cluster?

Tags: virtualbox, kubernetes, minikube

I am running minikube on my Mac laptop.  I am using VirtualBox to host the minikube virtual machine, following the [official instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#quickstart).

I would like a pod that I am going to deploy into the cluster to be able to ping a server I will be running on my laptop.  Assuming (for now) that I am not defining a Kubernetes Service of type ExternalName to represent that server, what IP or hostname should I use from within the program running in my pod?

**EDIT**: From my pod I can `ping 10.0.2.2` and get answers back.  However, trying to `telnet` to `10.0.2.2` on port `9092`, where I happen to have an H2 database running, just hangs.

Finally, `minikube ssh`, which apparently logs me into the VirtualBox VM, maybe? running as `docker`? results in all the same behaviors above, in case this matters, which suggests this is fundamentally a question, I suppose, about VirtualBox.

**EDIT #2**: A restart of VirtualBox solved the connection issue (!).  Nevertheless, `10.0.2.2` still seems like magic to me; I'd like to know where that IP comes from.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the ipv4 address listed under `vboxnet0`.  Look for the `vboxnet0` interface in the list of outputs for `ifconfig`.  Alternatively the address `10.0.2.2` will also map back to the host from the guest.

This IP address will be accessible from within the guest but not directly from within a pod.  To make it accessible from within a pod you will need to create a headless service that exposes this IP address.
See this answer for how to create a headless service:
[Minikube expose MySQL running on localhost as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354167/minikube-expose-mysql-running-on-localhost-as-service/43477742#43477742)

So for example I ran a server at port :8000 on my host and did the following to access it in a pod:

```
$ kubectl create -f service.yaml

----service.yaml----
apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata:
    name: my-service spec:
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 1443
          targetPort: 8000

$ kubectl create -f endpoint.yaml

----endpoint.yaml----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: my-service
subsets:
    - addresses:
        - ip: 192.168.99.1 #ipv4 address from vboxnet0
      ports:
        - port: 8000

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    2h
my-service   10.0.0.83    <none>        1443/TCP   17m
```

Then you can access the host service by using 10.0.0.83:1443 within a pod.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would I create a headless Service, which requires me to create an Endpoint, or a Service of type ExternalName, which I don't think does require me to create an Endpoint?

Comment: I just got this to work accessing a server on my host using a headless service in minikube w/virtualbox using yaml files nearly identical to those linked and the ip @ vboxnet0.  I think you could also use ExternalName but I think you will need to add a DNS entry into your cluster to map to the IP.  I am less familliar with ExternalName unfortunately.

Comment: Interestingly, with no other magic on my part, `ping 10.0.2.2` from within a shell prompt set up by `kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never` gets an answer.  Where can I read more about this magic (to me!) `10.0.2.2` address?

Comment: I don't really know too much more about it other than virtualbox always maps this back to the host