# Connect to local database from inside minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to access a MySQL database hosted inside a docker container on localhost from inside a minikube pod with little success. I tried the solution described [Minikube expose MySQL running on localhost as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354167/minikube-expose-mysql-running-on-localhost-as-service) but to no effect. I have modelled my solution on the service we use on AWS but it does not appear to work with minikube. My service reads as follows

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata: 

  name: mysql-db-svc

  namespace: external

spec: 
  type: ExternalName
  ExternalName: 172.17.0.2
```

...where I try to connect to my database from inside a pod using "mysql-db-svc" on port 3306 but to no avail. If I try and CURL the address "mysql-db-svc" from inside a pod it cannot resolve the host name.

Can anybody please advise a frustrated novice?

Comment: Check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354167/minikube-expose-mysql-running-on-localhost-as-service/77981424#answer-77981424

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using ubuntu with Minikube and my database runs outside of minikube inside a docker container and can be accessed from localhost @ 172.17.0.2. My Kubernetes service for my external mysql container reads as follows:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-db-svc
  namespace: external
spec: 
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 10.0.2.2
```

Then inside my .env for a project my DB_HOST is defined as

```
mysql-db-svc.external.svc
```

... the name of the service "mysql-db-svc" followed by its namespace "external" with "svc"

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: could you please provide some more details on how you got it to work ?

Comment: Thanks! but this did not help, I am on a Mac and have mysql deployed locally. I want to access it from a spring boot application running on Minikube.

Comment: @prime That's impressive, but how did you figure out the magic externalName there? Where does the 10.0.2.2 come from?

Comment: Nevermind, this explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732276/1035008

Comment: what about the port on which mysql is running.

Comment: It does not work, it says `Could not resolve host`

Comment: @Matteo how did you solve this for you?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk yes, you can check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72373121/cannot-reach-localhost-of-host-machine-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you should also create an Endpoint for this service as it's external.

In your case, the Endpoints definition should be as follows:

```
kind: "Endpoints"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: mysql-db-svc
  namespace: external
subsets: 
- addresses:
  - ip: "10.10.1.1"
  ports:
    port: 3306
```

You can read about the **external sources** on Kubernetes [Defining a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) docs.

Comment: In 2022, kubernetes docs say [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) takes in a `string` and not an address. So, in case  `ExternalName` doesn't work, you can also use the simpler option of [services-without-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your service type is `ExternalName` which only fits in cloud environment such as AWS and GKE. To run your service locally change the service type to `NodePort` which will assign a static NodePort between 30000-32767. If you need to assign a static port on your own so that minikube won't pick a random port for you define that in your service definition under ports section like this `nodePort: 32002`.

And also I don't see any selector that points to your MySQL deployment in your service definition. So include the corresponding selector key pair (e.g. `app: mysql-server`) in your service definition under `spec` section. That selector should match with the selector you have defined in MySQL deployment definition.

So your service definition should be like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-db-svc
  namespace: external
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql-server
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 32002
  type: NodePort
```

After you deploy the service you can hit the MySQL service via http://{minikube ip}:32002 Replace {minikube ip} with actual minikube ip.

Or else you can get the access URL for the service with following command

```
minikube service <SERVICE_NAME> --url
```

Replace the  with actual name of the service. In your case it is `mysql-db-svc`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, greatly sppreciated. But the mysql instance is not inside the cluster, it's external to minikube.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing a similar problem where I needed to connect a POD inside minikube with a SQL Server container on the machine.

I noticed that minikube is itself a container in the local docker environment and during it's setup it creates a local docker network `minikube`. I connected my local SQL Server container to this `minikube` docker network using `docker network connect minikube <SQL Server Container Name> --ip=<any valid IP on the minikube network subent>`.

I was now able to access the local SQL Server container using the IP address on `minikube` network.

Comment: Is this all you had to do? I tried the same but I still get the error:
`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<Container IP in the Minikube network>' (111)`

Answer (score 1):

As an addon to @Crou s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964918/2715083) from 2018, In 2022, kubernetes docs say [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) takes in a `string` and not an address. So, in case  `ExternalName` doesn't work, you can also use the simpler option of [services-without-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

You can also refer to this Google Cloud Tech [video](https://youtu.be/fvpq4jqtuZ8) for how this `services-without-selectors` concept works

Answer (score 0):

Above solution somehow doesn't work for me. Finally it works below in terraform

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "host" {
    metadata {
        name = "minikube-host"

        labels = {
            app = "minikube-host"
        }

        namespace = "default"
    }

    spec {
        port {
            name = "app"
            port = 8082
        }
        cluster_ip = "None"
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_endpoints" "host" {
    metadata {
        name = "minikube-host"
        namespace = "default"
    }
    subset {
        address {
            // This ip comes from command: minikube ssh 'grep host.minikube.internal /etc/hosts | cut -f1'
            ip = "192.168.65.2"
        }

        port {
            name     = "app"
            port     = 8082
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can access the local service (e.g, postgres, or mysql) in my mac with host `minikube-host.default.svc.cluster.local` from k8s pods.

The plain yaml file version and more details can be found at [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8439#issuecomment-799801736).

The minikube host access `host.minikube.internal` detail can [be found here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/).

On the other hand, the raw ip address from command `minikube ssh 'grep host.minikube.internal /etc/hosts | cut -f1'`(e.,g `"192.168.65.2"`), can be used as the service host directly, instead of `127.0.0.1/localhost` at code. And no more above configurations required.