# Obtain host IP from within Minikube hosted on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, minikube

I'm trying to access a locally hosted service from within a Minikube cluster running on Hyper-V. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952240/connect-to-local-database-from-inside-minikube-cluster) question the user made use of the VirtualBox-provided IP (`10.0.2.2`) to loop back to the host IP.

Is there an equivalent IP for Hyper-V?

I'm running Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro with Minikube v0.28.2.

Comment: Maybe it's more related to the communication topic between host and Hyper-V guest VM,  look at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1185502/hyper-v-access-host-in-offline-mode).

Comment: How did you configure Hyper-V switch for `Minikube`? What OS do you use for Hyper-V?

Comment: @mk_sta I've updated the question. As for the switch I created an external network as per the instructions on https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IP of `Hyper-V External switch` created for minikube connection rendering.

1. Open your `Hyper-V manager` and check the name of `External virtual
   switch`. In this [guide](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c) it's called "Primary Virtual Switch".
2. Check the IP address for this `Hyper-V` network interface on your
   Windows 10 machine.
3. Try to use this IP address in your minikube project for
   communication purposes with a service residing on the local
   machine.

I've used `busybox` Pod and tested it on my machine:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

I was able to ping target local machine from the Pod's container:

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- ping XXX.XX.XX.XX
```