# Connecting to MySQL container from Minikube pod

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm literally going crazy about this problem, I'll try to provide as many info as I can.

I have a MySQL 8 container running in Docker which is accessible from my machine at the IP that Docker assigns to it, so something like `172.17.0.2`, while using `localhost` gives the error below and this is already a strange issue.
I have a Minikube 1.10 cluster running using Docker as driver (so Minikube is basically running as a container) and I want to connect to my MySQL container from a pod inside Minikube and, hopefully, expose MySQL as a service in order to use Kubernetes DNS.

After every solution I tried I always get this error:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql:3306' (111)`

I think I've read everything possible on the internet, I've tried everything said in these questions:

[Minikube expose MySQL running on localhost as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354167/minikube-expose-mysql-running-on-localhost-as-service)

[Connect to local database from inside minikube cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952240/connect-to-local-database-from-inside-minikube-cluster)

Like creating a service and an endpoint by hand and connecting the MySQL container to Minikube network but no luck till now.

Using a `busybox` I'm able to ping the container using the IP in the Minikube network but not using the service name as explained in the first link I wrote above.

Furthermore, I can confirm that MySQL has `bind-address = *` and the user is allow to connect remotely as shown here:

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER(), @@bind_address;
+----------------+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() | @@bind_address |
+----------------+----------------+
| dbuser@%       | *              |
+----------------+----------------+

I think I gave all the possible info, if not let me know.
```

Comment: Can you run the database as a Kubernetes StatefulSet, instead of trying to cross from one container environment to another?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd prefer to avoid it in order to simulate a real environment where the DB is outside the cluster