# Cannot reach localhost of host machine in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes kind cluster with the following configuration:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    kubeadmConfigPatches:
      - |
        kind: InitConfiguration
        imageGCHighThresholdPercent: 70
        evictionHard:
          nodefs.available: "0%"
          nodefs.inodesFree: "0%"
          imagefs.available: "70%"
        nodeRegistration:
          kubeletExtraArgs:
            node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80
        protocol: TCP
      - containerPort: 443
        hostPort: 443
        protocol: TCP
```

Image version: `docker.io/kindest/base:v20220305-b67a383f`

I am trying to connect to my localhost by using `ExternalName`:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-external-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.0.2.2
    ports:
      - port: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-external-service
  labels:
    app: my-external-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
```

According to this answer: [why do we use 10.0.2.2 to connect to local web server instead of using computer ip address in android client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer/34732276#34732276), that IP should be the localhost in my local machine.

Then I run a container to debug this setup:

```
kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=alpine --restart=Never -- sh
```

`8.8.8.8` is pingable, but unfortunately I cannot ping `10.0.2.2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was not a kubernetes problem, but a docker one **since I am running Kind**. The solution is described in this github comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1200#issuecomment-647145134

the address is not `10.0.2.2`, but `172.17.0.1` which is your docker bridge default gateway.

Also we need to add this `iptables` rule **in the host machine**

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport <your server port> -j ACCEPT
```