# Access service on host OS using minikube and kvm

Tags: networking, kubernetes, minikube, kvm

WHat I am currenly trying to do is access a mysql service running on myhost OS from a pod running inside a kvm VM running minikube

host os: linux/ubuntu
configuration: minikube --driver=kvm2

(Host OS hosting mysql) -> (KVM) -> (minikube) -> (pod)
--------------^-------------------------------------------------------v

Answers found thus far are either vague or nor applicable to what I'm trying to achieve

A solution would be to run a stateful set hosting a mysql instance but that is not what I'm after at this point as this service will not be deployed like that in the cloud

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minikube expose MySQL running on localhost as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354167/minikube-expose-mysql-running-on-localhost-as-service)

Comment: Yah it did, Thanks